# How to get the direction for a place in Android

Tags: android, maps, android-maps, direction

I am creating an Android Application, And I need the direction for a particular place in a string/JSON/XML or any raw format, so I can direct the user to goto the place without leaving my application. I will be very thankful for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by means on [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) from **Google Maps**. I am not sure about your requirements but in general, the steps are the following:

1. Make a request:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputFormat?parameters

2. Specify JSON as your output format.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?parameters

3. Supply your request with parameters like *origin*, *destination* and your *API key*:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/jsonorigin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY